# Twilio send optional parameters TwiML JavaScript Ajax Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-php

Is it possible to send optinal parameters to my twilio twiml file and use them in a php script? Its because im using a generated userid in my phonegap app. If the call is connected i want to send the user id to twiml and check in the php if the call was "completed" and set then values in a mysql db for the userid.

Somethinglike:

Twiml:

```
<Response>
  <Dial action="http://blabla.com/dial.php" method="POST">
    555-5555
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#dialButton").click(function() {
                           params = { "userid" : $(userid).val()};
                           connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
                           });
```

Php:

```
$user = $_POST["userid"];
```

Is this the right way?If not how can i solve the problemt?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the attributes that will be sent to the action URL:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-parameters

It looks like it doesn't contain the userID (I assume you mean accountSID or subaccountSID?).

According to this article (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/05/how-to-track-and-report-your-twilio-usage.html) you may want to use the StatusCallback paramater when making a call, I don't know how that plays with what's going on with your phonegap application, I'm not familiar with that technology.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional

I hope this helps or at least gets you in the direction you need to go.

Comment: what i did mean was a custom parameter like "userid".

Comment: So, you have a userID that's associated with a phone number? That would be easy enough to work with. Dial has a callsid which you can use to access the Call object which will have the to and from numbers.